# How to pass and handle Exceptions through HTTP responses in Spring?

Tags: spring, exception, resttemplate

I have a Client and Server module in my Spring project running on separate ports. The Client module makes a POST request to the Server via a RestTemplate. The Server-Module throws a custom Exception with a custom error-message. Currently, in my Project, the Server has a RestControllerAdvice Class that handles such exceptions as follows:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class AppRestControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(ApiException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public MessageData handle(ApiException e) {
        MessageData data = new MessageData();
        data.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        return data;
    }
}
```

On the Client side, the following method catches the Response from the Server.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class AppRestControllerAdvice {
    @ExceptionHandler(ApiException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public MessageData handle(ApiException e) {
        MessageData data = new MessageData();
        data.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        return data;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Throwable.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public MessageData handle(Throwable e) {
        MessageData data = new MessageData();
        data.setMessage("UNKNOWN ERROR- " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Whenever the Exception is thrown on the server, here is what I receive on the Client

```
{
  "message": "UNKNOWN ERROR- org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request"
}
```

My question is, h**ow do I retrieve the Custom Exception message that originated on the Server**?

**Also**, why isn't the correct RestControllerAdvice module on the Client side picking up the error? (The *INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR* method catches the error instead of the *BAD_REQUEST* method.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how do I retrieve the Custom Exception message that originated on the Server?

To retrieve the orignal exception message you have to use dedicated `ResponseErrorHandler` that is capable of extracting that information, rather than using the default one (`DefaultResponseErrorHandler` - which I assume you use because of the message you got - `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request`).

Create:

```
public class CustomerResponseErrorHandler extends DefaultResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {

        // here you have access to the response's body which potentially contains the exception message you are interested in  
        // simply extract it if possible and throw an exception with that message
        // in other case you can simply call `super.handlerError()` - do whatever suits you

    }
}
```

Then use it with your `RestTemplate`:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder
          .errorHandler(new CustomerResponseErrorHandler())
          .build();
    }

}
```

> Also, why isn't the correct RestControllerAdvice module on the Client side picking up the error? (The INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR method catches the error instead of the BAD_REQUEST method.)

The correct method is executed - your `RestTemplate` at the moment is throwing `HttpClientErrorException` which is not an `ApiException`. It is a `Throwable` though.

Comment: Basically one need to be aware of the exception before hand to map/parse the exception to your custom exception handler.